# How to set X-frame-options and Content Security Policy on netlify?

Tags: netlify

I want to ask how to set X-Frame-Options and Content Security Policy on netlify. As I have static website and its deployment server is netlify and I don't have any configuration file(netlify.toml). So, where can I set X-frame-Options and Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 1):

Save a plain text file called `_headers` to the publish directory of your site (see [details and syntax](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/headers/)). For instance:

```
# a path:
/templates/index.html
  # headers for that path:
  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
# any other paths:
/*
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
```

Also you can use specific [CSP packages](http://csplite.com/csp249/#Netlify_CSP_packages) for Netlify. Generally they do the same - add headers into `_headers` file, but some of they do calculate hashes for scripts.